# Web Server Responding, despite broken network path

Tags: web-server, router

I am encountering a strange problem. Its about [this](http://www.nepalipatra.com) website. If you see its [tracert report](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools/tracert/?tool_id=68&token=&toolhandler_redirect=0&ip=www.nepalipatra.com), you will notice that 4 router towards the end is not responding, despite this, the request reaches its destination and the website is delivered to the client.

Can someone put some light to the situation and explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traceroutes don't necessarily show all hops in the network, because some routers don't react correctly to provide the necessary data for traceroute to do it's job.

Comment: So, you mean those routers are actually responding, although the tracert report gave a not responding report.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "responding".  They're certainly *routing*, which is the important bit, they're just not responding correctly to the packets that traceroute is using.

Comment: This might be silly, but if i ping one of those routers like vl911.core5a.lon3.rackspace.net, it's again not responding. So, by what you mean, that router is also not responding to the ping packet, not just tracert SYN packet.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But traceroute doesn't usually use TCP SYN packets, it uses UDP.

Comment: Can you suggest me anything, that could enable the router to respond to those requests?

Comment: Buy Rackspace?  That traceroute doesn't show the full path doesn't matter, the routers are working correctly.

Comment: traceroute, ping, and http connectivity are entirely different things, and can be enabled/disabled as the firewall and router admins see fit. For example, I can ping one of my servers at work, but can't traceroute to it (my work firewall blocks it). When running traceroute to my work firewall, there are routers at my home ISP and my work ISP that give no response, but routers further down the line respond perfectly well.